# Firebase not recognizing my root ('/') express route?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm running a node.js with express and pug.  My routes are handled this way:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

app.get('/pages/:page', (req, res) => {
    res.render(req.params["page"]);
});
```

Everything works fine locally, both if I run the app with 'node index.js' and if I emulate firebase with 'firebase emulators:start'.

However, once I deploy to Firebase, the first route ('/') doesn't work.  I get the "Site Not Found" error.  But if I go to the same view via the second route, with '.../pages/index', it works fine.

This only happens through my custom domain.  If I use either of the two firebase assigned URLs, i.e. PROJECT-NAME.web.app or PROJECT-NAME.firebaseapp.com, it works correctly.

And it all *was* working correctly.  I cloned my dev directory and started deploying from the new directory instead.  That's when it stopped working.  But I didn't change my core index.js file, or move anything around.

There's nothing of note in the Firebase logs.

EDIT:

Here's my firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites" : [
        {
            "source": "**", 
            "function": "app" }
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2: I gave up and moved the whole thing to Heroku.  Everything works great.  Much simpler.  Thanks for responses.**

Comment: What are you deploying to Firebase?

Comment: Please include your Firebase Hosting config (from inside `firebase.json`) in your question.

Comment: @Phil Not sure what you are asking for, but a full node.js application, with my core app ("index.js") in functions.

Comment: @DavidRea that is indeed what I was asking for (specifically that you are deploying _functions_)